# jQuery append only works if I select html in admin section

Tags: jquery, javascript

The following jQuery code works as expected, in that it inserts the specified html after the closing  tag.

```
$( "html" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
```

However, that's a clunky place to insert it. Ideally, I'd like to append it to , but using any other element stops it working.

```
$( "body" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
```

and

```
$( ".exampleclass" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
```

both do nothing - no errors, no anything.

Why is this?

Comment: When and where are you specifically executing this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These  three lines work as expected , There is a problem maybe with other code before these lines that prevent the execution of your script;

In case just fire the browser console in this page and try them here

```
$( "html" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
$( "body" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
$( ".topbar" ).append( "<div id='bf_rsvp_note_display'></div>" );
```